# Setting default image to column in Sqlite database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.data.sqlite

In my project I am using `System.Data.Sqlite`. I want to create a table with image column. I am setting default image (i.e. NoImageAvailable). But it gives me error i.e. `SQL logic error or missing database near "@img": syntax error`. Here is my code.

```
byte[] img = null;

        try
        {
            img = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + 
                                    @"\Resources\General_Images\NOPHOTO.jpg");
        }
        catch { }

        string qry = "CREATE TABLE [CLIENT_MSTR] " +
            "([ID] INTEGER IDENTITY," + 
            "[CLIENT_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
            "[ABBR] VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT '" + string.Empty + "' UNIQUE," +
            "[PHOTO] BLOB DEFAULT @img)";

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, m_dbConnection);
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary, img.Length);
        cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = img;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch { }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can parametrize a blob in a DDL statement. The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) say:

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and
>   preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

Whether you can include the image data in this format, I don't know; converting to the X'..' format probably is not the problem but to create and feed in such a long string may be tricky. There is an [option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_blob_literal) that controls it in theory:

> SQLITE_OMIT_BLOB_LITERAL
>
> ```
> When this option is defined, it is not possible 
> to specify a blob in an SQL statement using the X'ABCD' syntax.
> ```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059266/sqlite-setting-the-default-value-in-create-table) also rules it out, ar least by parameters..

If you manage to get it to work in a literal, please do post it here!